# Loading Multiple API request on the same view using Retrofit

Tags: android, retrofit

I'm loading News Data from https://newsapi.org using Retrofit, i was successfully loading news from one source, when trying to load news  from two sources, Android .

***Here is Stack Trace image :***

[image: Stack Trace image]

My Falling Codes are

```
for (int i = 0; i < config.NEWS_SOURCE.length; i++) {
       Call<Article> call= clientInterface.getNews(config.NEWS_SOURCE[i], config.NEWS_API_KEY);
       call.enqueue(new Callback<Article>() {
           @Override
           public void onResponse(Call<Article> call, Response<Article> response) {

               List<News> news = response.body().getArticles();
            /*
            newsRecylcerView.setAdapter(new NewsAdapter(news,
                    R.layout.news_list, getApplicationContext()));
                    */

               Log.d("News from API", "Number of movies: " + news.size());
               Log.d("News From List: ", news.get(0).getTitle());

           }

           @Override
           public void onFailure(Call<Article> call, Throwable t) {
               Log.e("Error we received", t.toString());

           }
       });
   }
```

Comment: There is no such thing as a "null Exception Error" in Java, I'll assume you're talking about a NullPointerException. If you are, then you should already know which line it comes from, without that information it would not be possible to help you.

Comment: yes, i had typo

Comment: Post the stack trace of your error.

Comment: what's line 53 of main activity?

Answer (score 0):

Your error is on this line:

```
List<News> news = response.body().getArticles();
```

With the little information you provided, my best guess is your `body()` is `null`, and you're trying to call `getArticles()` on a `null` object.

Probably one of your news source is returning no data.

Answer (score -2):

Avoid for loop to get data from API call. Use single call for single request and next after getting on succeccsful response. First of all try to watch the response and create your response pojo object model according to response.

Probably you are trying to getting data by tag or index which doesn’t exist. Log your whole response first

Comment: yes, i corrected it, but i still i have the problem

I want news from all source to be displayed on the view, but news from last  source are only shown